# Best way to pass dynamic html to service

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I currently have an angular asp .net mvc application with multiple tenants, each tenant has their own set of html code. At the moment we have some html stored in a static variable.

GenericHelper.cs

```
public static string Template = '<html code here>'
```

On the client side, there's an app service that would reuse this bit of code.

index.js

```
mapService.getTemplate(searchparams).success(function (data) {

})
```

MapService.cs

```
public async TestDto GetTemplate(GetTemplateInput input)
{
     return GenericHelper.Template
}
```

but now I want to return a more dynamic template, one based on which tenant is appearing. So if it's tenant1, display tenant1 template, if tenant2 display tenant2 template. Sure I can do this with a bunch of if and else statements but it's very hard to manage.

We have bits of angular code that displays html based on which tenant it is on the js side of the application.

.js

```
vm.template = abp.rootTemplatePath + "views/users/partials/userGallery.cshtml";
```

.cshtml

```
<div ng-include="vm.activeTemplate"></div>
```

I am looking to save html code to each tenant set of html code. `tenant1/views/users/partials/template.cshtml` and pass it to my appservice, what's the best way to do this? What I tried yesterday was read html from a page asynchronously using code from here https://gomakethings.com/getting-html-asynchronously-from-another-page/ but unfortunately it's an asp.netmvc application and `abp.rootTemplatePath + "views/users/partials/template.cshtml"` is not a url that's reachable. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

My main goal is to get template.cshtml in a string format and pass it to MapService.GetTemplate

Comment: I'm not to sure about your problem here but it seems like Partial View is what you are looking for. They can take a model. That way, you wouldn't need to store the html in a variable.

Comment: I created a partial view, 'template.cshtml', just unsure how to convert that to html string. razor probably has a way to convert it to string by reading the file, but is that the best approach here? That bit of code is triggered very often. I feel like read/write operations are very intensive. @the_lotus